# Showing structure group in WEBDAV form SDL Tridion

Tags: tridion, webdav

In our installation, I can only see Building Block from when connecting to CME using WEBDAV. I am wondering whether it is possible to show structure group as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Only the Building Blocks folder is exposed to WebDAV. This behavior is not configurable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, at least I know now it is not possible.